# Gunsmithing and special bullets

Tags: pathfinder-1e, crafting

Does [Gunsmithing](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/gunsmithing) allow you to create bullets made from [special materials](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/special-materials) at 10% of the cost of buying bullets of the same type?

Comment: This question is worded weirdly. 10% the cost of what? It parses like it's asking: "can I make adamantine bullets for 1/10th the price of regular bullets?", but I'm pretty sure that must be like, 10% of the cost of the material, or 10% extra on top of regular bullet pricing, or something that isn't about making bullets that are more powerful than usual yet one tenth the regular price. Could someone who understands how the 10% fits in edit the question to clarify so that I as a newbie can understand what's going on here?

Comment: @doppelgreener: The concept here is that crafting is cheaper than buying. So, "can I craft adamantine bullets for 1/10th the normal purchase price of adamantine bullets?"

Comment: Reading the link under "Gunsmithing" provided should adequately explain what the question is asking.

Comment: @thelr Thanks, that makes sense out of it. I see the spot I missed now!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Yes.

Gunsmithing states:

> You can craft **bullets, pellets, and black powder** for a cost in raw materials equal to 10% of the price. [...]

Emphasis mine. That includes everything called bullet, such as [Bullet](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons/weapon-descriptions/ammunition/bullet), [Adamantine Bullet](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons/weapon-descriptions/ammunition/bullet-adamantine), [Pitted Bullet](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons/weapon-descriptions/ammunition/bullet-pitted), or [Silver Bullet](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons/weapon-descriptions/ammunition/bullet-silver). Note that these are listed as specific items, sometimes with different abilities than regular special material weapons. There seems to be no restriction on crafting other types of bullets though, and, being bullets, they are price-reduced as well.

A [full list of Bullet pricing](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2q0hq&page=2?spellslinger-no-PFS-booo#87) can was compiled by Nefreet on the paizo boards. It's noteworthy to say that this list was copied to the PFS Shared GM Prep Folder's GM's Guide to Gunslingers (and PFS is quite RAW by design).

Comment: A lot of materials give a cost in lb / flat cost for weapons. Can you not make bullets out of them?

Comment: No reason to believe cold iron is different. Per http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons/firearms a normal bullet costs 1 gp and an adamantine bullet 61 gp, using the standard +60gp per missile cost for adamantine ammo per http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/special-materials#TOC-Adamantine. Should be able to apply to any of the materials that can be used for ammo, so a cold iron bullet that costs "double normal" would be valued at 2 gp, and cost .2 gp for a gunsmith to make.